# In which direction does the current flow if we connect batteries with the same poles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current

We bind two batteries with voltage 2V and 1.7V  with inner resistance 0.2Ω and 0.1Ω in parallel series in such way that we bind each positive poles and negative poles together.

What current runs trough the circle? What is the voltage between contact points of the batteries?
In the circle we include resistor R=2Ω.
What is the voltage between contact points of the batteries now?
What current flows through the circle?

[image]

**Solving:**

First, I drew the electrical circle. Then I noticed that the wire is connecting + from first battery to + from first battery. I looked if the voltages of batteries are different and they are - therefore the current will flow from bigger to smaller electrical potential.

Question: From where does the current flows: From - pole of 1.7V to - pole of 2V or vice versa? Why? How does this work?

I solved this problem like this: What is the potential difference between the two batteries? 0.3V. I applied Ohm's Law and got the current.

In solution sheet it was writen $I= I_{1} -I_{2}$

For the voltage between the contact points of batteries I would instantly answer 0.3V, because that is the potential of which can current actually flow. But the correct answer is 1.7V. Is my thinking even correct?

$U= U_{1} -IR_{1}=U_{2} +IR_{2}= 1.7V$

Comment: Could you please add the picture of the circuit? It would be much easier for us to understand what you have.

Comment: @FGSUZ Hope it helps.

Comment: Please add those inner resistances to the circuit schematics. The reason is that two ideal voltage sources at different voltages can't be connected in parallel with no other components. Well, they can, but the result is nonsensical because the implication is that (in this case) 2=1.7. It's the electrical engineering equivalent of dividing zero by zero. To actually obtain an answer, you would need to incorporate the resistance of the wire or  the internal resistances of one or both batteries. In this case, you're given those internal resistance values.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Fixed it.

Comment: I still see just the two batteries. Those internal resistances are actual circuit resistances that belong in the schematic. Otherwise, you won't be able to correctly apply Ohm's law and Kirchhoff's voltage and current laws (or whatever technique you're using to find the currents and the voltage drops). As long as a resistive component is present in the loop, note that you can add voltages in series (e.g., $2+(-1.7)$).